# Can a library that depends on System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler be deployed to Linux

Tags: linux, cross-platform, .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard

I am looking at using the [Consul library for .NET](https://github.com/PlayFab/consuldotnet) which supports NETSTANDARD1.3. As I was adding the package I saw it depends on [System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler/), which in turns adds the win32 primitives package.

I can't find any documentation to say how these packages work on Linux. I would assume they won't work, but it is possible they provide a shim-layer.

Does anyone have any experience with these packages?

EDIT:

Deploying to Ubuntu as a Self Contained Deployment results in the following.

`` Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Net.Http.CurlHandler' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Http' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'HttpInitializer' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'System.Net.Http.Native': The specified module could not be found.
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
   at Interop.HttpInitializer.EnsureCurlIsInitialized()
   at Interop.HttpInitializer..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.HttpInitializer.Initialize()
   at Interop.Http..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Interop.Http.GetSupportedFeatures()
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler..ctor()
   at Consul.ConsulClient.ConsulClientConfigurationContainer..ctor()
   at Consul.ConsulClient..ctor(Action`1 configOverride, Action`1 clientOverride, Action`1 handlerOverride)
   at REstateScratchPad.Program.Main(String[] args)
Aborted (core dumped) ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to install the SDK, since I was able to get this working. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Are you following the steps detailed in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/ (also detailed below)?

I say this because I built a test app that works fine without the SDK installed at all:

1. Edit your `project.json` as per the guide above and remove `"platform": true`. Add a `runtimes: {}` element, for me that's:
   `"runtimes": {
   "win81-x64": {},
   "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {}
   }`
2. After I did that, I was able to do a `dotnet restore` and `dotnet build -r ubuntu.14.04-x64` which worked, but only dropped 3 files in the directory and couldn't run without the SDK.
3. I did `dotnet publish -c release -r ubuntu.14.04-x64` and started up a Vagrant box running Ubuntu 14.04, `apt-get install libunwind8`, and then run my program: `/vagrant/bin/release/netcoreapp1.0/ubuntu.14.04-x64/publish/ConsoleApp1`. All the program does is the example function located in the README.md of the [Consul.NET project](https://github.com/PlayFab/consuldotnet#example), and it was able to print "Hello Consul" correctly after I started a copy of Consul in the VM.

Comment: I think it is the "platform": true configuration that causes the issue.

I have moved to .CSPROJ project structure, and that is no longer a setting. Not sure where it is now!

Answer (score 0):

Linux does in fact support that dependency as it is part of the .NETStandard and has shims in place for a CURL handler.

Deploying the application did result in errors as seen in the original post, but installing the SDK solved those.

Sidenote: Didn't think I would need the SDK to run a Self contained deployment.